# Use twitter callback only after follow

Tags: javascript, twitter, twitter-oauth

I have created a twitter follow button. In that button I want a callback function. So that when a user will follow it will show an alert kind of thing. But the thing is it is currently showing the message even user is not logged in with his twitter account. I want that it should show the message only after follow. My code is like this

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/twitter" class="twitter-follow-button" data-show-count="false" data-size="large" data-show-screen-name="false">Follow @twitter</a> 

    <script>
            function show_message(event) {
        console.log('test');
    }
    window.twttr = (function (d,s,id) {
                                        var t, js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
                                        if (d.getElementById(id)) return; js=d.createElement(s); js.id=id;
                                        js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"; fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
                                        return window.twttr || (t = { _e: [], ready: function(f){ t._e.push(f) } });
                                        }(document, "script", "twitter-wjs"));
                                    twttr.ready(function (twttr) {
                                        twttr.events.bind('follow', show_message);
                                    });
</script>
```

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/NewUserFiddle/f7k3mj16/1/) link

Comment: This alert is expected to pop up before the user is redirected to the link?

Comment: Only thing I want is show the message when user makes follow

Comment: But remember he/she is clicking on a link. The default behavior is to be redirected to another page. Correct me if I'm wrong: the user clicks the "follow" button, the message is shown and he/she is not redirected. Is that right?

Comment: Yes I understand. Then how could I achieve that what I am looking for?

Comment: The thing I want is if user is already logged in with his twitter account then it will make follow as user click on the button and the message will be shown. But if user is not logged in then it will not show the message until he has not followed

Answer (score 2):

The feature you're asking about is no longer supported by Twitter.

You can read the announcement and the reason on [this page](https://twittercommunity.com/t/forthcoming-change-to-web-intent-events/54718).

In brief, events are now raised when the Intent is triggered and no longer after it's completed. The change was related to these events being unreliable on mobiles with native apps catching these links so it's impossible to get an event after the Intent is complete because we're no longer in the browser but in a native app.

To address this issue, all events are now raised when the Intent is triggered so the result you're getting is actually correct and intended.

The change in the JavaScript Twitter's widgets is in effect since Nov '15 2015.